# Filtering an array with foreach and for loop

Tags: php

I'm pulling data from mssql database into an array called

```
$results2
```

[image]

I need to echo out each 'Item' only one time, so this example should only echo out:

"52PTC84C25" and "0118SGUANN-R"

I can do this easily with:

```
$uniqueItems = array_unique(array_map(function ($i) { return $i['ITEM']; }, $results2));
```

The issue is when i try to echo out the other items associated with those values. I'm not sure how to even begin on echoing this data. I've tried:

```
foreach($uniquePids as $items)
{
    echo $items."<br />";

        foreach($results2 as $row)
        {
             echo $row['STK_ROOM']."-".$row['BIN']."<br />";
        }
 }
```

This returns close to what I need, but not exactly:

[image]

This is what I need:

[image]

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and use `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT()`

Comment: Group-by in PHP: `foreach ($results2 as $i) $grouped[$i['ITEM']] = $i;`.

Comment: `GROUP BY` is good, or instead of using `array_map` do :
`array_unique(array_values(array_column($result, 'ITEM')))`.

Comment: @mickmackusa the `BIN` changes so OP needs to figure out additional logic.

Comment: I think it's still cool.  Set me up an sqlfiddle so that I can code from my phone.

Comment: Please post the data as text. Also, to help the potential answerers to use the data please use `var_export()` instead of `var_dump()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your resultset is ordered by `ITEM`...

```
$item = null;  // set non-matching default value
foreach ($results2 as $row) {
    if($row['ITEM'] != $item) {
        echo "{$row['ITEM']}<br>";  // only echo first occurrence 
    }
    echo "{$row['STK_ROOM']}-{$row['BIN']}<br>";
    $item = $row['ITEM'];  // update temp variable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if` condition in the code will check if the `ITEM` has already been printed or not.

```
$ary = array();
foreach($results2 as $row)
{
    if(!in_array($row['ITEM'], $ary))
    {
        echo $row['STK_ROOM']."-".$row['BIN']."<br />";
        $ary[] = $row['ITEM'];
    }
}
```

Comment: `in_array()` is not very efficient.  Try implementing `isset()` instead.

Comment: using `isset()` we can only check if the key is set, but how to check if a specific value has been echoed or not with `isset()`

Comment: The truth is: you don't even need to maintain an array of previously encountered strings.  Think of a better way.

Comment: You can have the list of keys like that : `array_unique(array_keys(array_column($result, 'ITEM')))` or use `array_filter` and create your function to remove duplications...